Make a simple router inside single htm file
I'm new to react, I'm trying to make a page with two routers like the following:
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-router-dom@4.2.2/umd/react-router-dom.min.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
    
<div id="root" class="container p-5 m-5 "></div>

<script  type="text/babel">          
  function MyForm () {    
    return (
      <form>
        my formmmmmmmmm
      </form>
    ); 
  }
</script>
 
<script  type="text/babel">
  function Result() {
    return (<b>result</b>) ;
  } 
</script>
    
<script type="text/babel">            
  const { Link,BrowserRouter, Routes , Route,} = ReactRouterDOM;   
  function App(){   
    return (    
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-6 col-sm-4 bg-white mx-auto">        
          <div className="row  bg-light my-1">       
            <div className="col-6 border-end">
              <Link to="/result"> Result  </Link>
            </div>
            <div className="col-6">
              <Link to="/MyForm"> MyForm </Link>
            </div>
          </div>
          <Routes>
            <Route path='/MyForm' element={<MyForm/>} />
            <Route path='/result' element={<Result/>} />
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
     
  const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
  root.render(       
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>     
  );      
</script>

But I'm getting the following errors:

React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined


Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined

I searched a lot but couldn't find anything useful. As you see , Element type is valid, because it is a function so it is also a component . They all are in the same html file.
Thank You
EDIT:
I removed hash routes. It doesn't help with the error anyway.
Plus using
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-router-dom@6.23.0/dist/umd/react-router-dom.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>

instead of
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-router-dom@4.2.2/umd/react-router-dom.min.js" crossorigin></script>

gives another errors like
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Routes')


Is is odd to have multiple <script  type="text/babel"> in a file like this?  - maybe that is actually a NEW question on my part here.

It's because notepad++ doesn't like JSX . I used several 
React-Router-DOM v4 doesn't export a Routes component. You likely meant to use React-Router-DOM v6 that does export the newer Routes component.
Here's the latest version as of this posting.
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-router-dom@6.23.0/dist/umd/react-router-dom.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>

React-Router is also used client-side to simulate a Multi-page app in what is effectively a Single Page App. The Link and Route components don't work with "hashes". Update the routes and links to be discrete paths.
Example:
<script type="text/babel">            
  const { Link, BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } = ReactRouterDOM; 
  
  function App() {   
    return (    
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-6 col-sm-4 bg-white mx-auto">        
          <div className="row  bg-light my-1">       
            <div className="col-6 border-end">
              <Link to="/result">Result</Link>
            </div>
            <div className="col-6">
              <Link to="/MyForm">MyForm</Link>
            </div>
          </div>
          <Routes>
            <Route path='/MyForm' element={<MyForm />} />
            <Route path='/result' element={<Result />} />
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
     
  const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
  root.render(       
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>     
  );      
</script>


Thank You, I actually tried this before posting the question, it gives an error which when I try to solve it gives another  errors .. I played with the versions existing in Unpkg for react, react-dom,react-router,and react-router-dom but couldn't run this code. About # you a're right. there is another component for it named HashRouter, But problem is not not-working but it is getting errors

@Vaheed01 Even with the HashRouter your routes and links wouldn't include the hash character. Can you edit the post to clarify what the issue you have with the v6 version is?

Yes, It gives me this "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Routes')" . Testing it is very easy. You just need a html file and internet connection.

@Vaheed01 I see. I'll take another look when I have some availability and get back to you.
